# Why not have access to the element?

Tags: c++, com, comtypes, com-interface

Here is my code:

```
#import "C:\...\.....\....tlb"

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    _ApplicationPtr myApp("InDesign.Application");
    DocumentPtr myDoc = myApp->ActiveDocument;
    SwatchesPtr mySwatches = myDoc->Swatches;

    cout << "Number of Swatch: " << mySwatches->Count << endl; // count = 10

    SwatchPtr first_swatch = mySwatches->Item[1L];
    SwatchPtr second_swatch = mySwatches->Item[2L]; 

    cout << first_swatch->Name; // correctly
    cout << second_swatch->Name; // crash

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Why can I not access the elements? The count is 10. Any ideas?

The line `SwatchPtr second_swatch = mySwatches->Item[2L];` compiles, but it is empty.

Error when accessing `second_swatch->Name`:

[image: error]

[image: error]

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? You have not provide any useful details. Does the code compile? Is there any errors being reported?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau updated question

Comment: Clearly the second pointer is NULL, but you are not checking for that. As for why it is NULL, you will have to consult the documentation for the Application you are accessing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau 
examples of C ++ does not. In C #, this code works.

Comment: What library are you using? What is a "Swatch"? We don't know anything about these objects.

Comment: @JordanMelo 
type library Adobe Indesign